# Convert results of EF query to string array

Tags: entity-framework, type-conversion

I have an EF query that returns integers.  I'm trying to build the selected values list for a MultiSelectList to build a select dropdown with MVC.  It has to be a string array (not a list).  I have the following:

```
string[] SelectedValues = context.ContactContactTypes.Where(x => x.ContactID == ID).Select(x => new { ID = x.ID.ToString() }).ToArray();
```

but it throws an error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'anonymous type: string ID[]' to 'string[]'

I can return a list and use a foreach to build the array using .NET to convert each value.  Is there a more elegant way of doing this within the EF query itself?

Comment: Don't project to anonymous type, select directly the desired value, `.Select(x => x.ID.ToString())`

Comment: That cleared the error - thanks!